# Updatesinglesalesforceobject from child business unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect, cloudpage

I need to update a sf contacts preferences from a preference center  page that lives in the child business unit.

I thought I could pass variables through to a processing page via form submit parameters
In the parent BU but I am perpetually getting a 500 error.

Are there issues or restrictions with just passing fields through form posts?

Comment: Did you check if the child BU was connected to SFDC via the connector? If you go to the connector settings in SFDC, is the BU checked?

Comment: Not connected @JeremyGarcia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Though for security reasons it’s not recommended to pass variables this way.  Utilize httppost function to encode.

Other than that, 500 errors are typically because you’ve screwed something up in ampscropt. Make sure the value types match the target sf record type.